# Can anyone identify what is going on with this bower install of angular-route?

Tags: angularjs, npm, angular-route-segment

```
bower not-cached    git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.4.6
bower resolve       git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.4.6
bower ENOTDIR       ENOTDIR: not a directory, mkdir '/var/folders/zq/2wb7gvvx2vz73y2g_b3kfm8w0000gn/T/daniellopez/bower'

Stack trace:
Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, mkdir '/var/folders/zq/2wb7gvvx2vz73y2g_b3kfm8w0000gn/T/daniellopez/bower'
    at Error (native)

Console trace:
Error
    at StandardRenderer.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:82:37)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:110:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Logger.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Logger.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:48:20
    at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:844:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:870:30
    at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:1122:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:788:41)
System info:
Bower version: 1.6.5
Node version: 4.2.1
OS: Darwin 14.4.0 x64
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem. Here is the key part of the error:

```
bower ENOTDIR       ENOTDIR: not a directory, mkdir '/var/folders/zq/2wb7gvvx2vz73y2g_b3kfm8w0000gn/T/daniellopez/bower'
```

Bower is getting a "not a directory" error trying to create a new folder inside:

```
/var/folders/zq/2wb7gvvx2vz73y2g_b3kfm8w0000gn/T/daniellopez
```

If you look at that location you should see something like this:

```
$ ls -alh /var/folders/zq/2wb7gvvx2vz73y2g_b3kfm8w0000gn/T/daniellopez 
-rwxr--r--  1 daniellopez  staff     0B Feb 21 17:10 /var/folders/zq/2wb7gvvx2vz73y2g_b3kfm8w0000gn/T/daniellopez
```

That's a 0 byte file, not a directory. Delete or move this file and you should be able to run your install command without issue.

Comment: This solved the issue for me, same error. Thanks @ptevans

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like some permissions issue, perhaps you used sudo with bower install? It is recommended not to use sudo with bower (unless you really know what you are doing and absolutely have to).

You can try to clean the cache by:

```
sudo bower cache clean --allow-root
```

And then run bower install again (without sudo).

See issue [720 on bower](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/720).

Comment: Hi. I tried this. Although it did clear out a bunch of trash that was there - it did not fix my problem. I am still having the same issue.